# Why did Howard Stark search for Captain America? Did he think he might be alive?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america

Movieverse I think. I know that Howard Stark is heading the search for Steve Rogers after he crashes in the plane. I think he keeps searching for a long time. But why? Does he know/think that Captain America may sill be alive because of the serum? Or is he merely searching for the remains to bury?

Comment: It's pretty standard policy to search for missing people after accidents. I'm sure he was involved because he was present and knew how to use the advanced submarine he was providing.

Comment: There are considerations towards enemies finding Rogers (dead or alive) and performing experiments on him, or using his body to advance their knowledge of the Super Serum. Also, when you're finding someone who is literally a government experiment, you'd want someone on hand with expertise/experience on what you might need to do differently; Stark was involved with the experiment from the beginning. Thing is, there could be any number of reasons, making this a difficult question to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably both.  Steve Rogers blood was the only remaining source of information on Dr. Erskin's formula for the Super Soldier Serum.  That alone would have made it imperative to either recover captain Rogers alive to continue fighting the war, or recover his remains to glean as much information as possible from his body.  There was still a war going on, and any advantage the Allied forces could either secure for themselves, or remove from the Axis powers grasp was imperative.

On a more personal note, Howard and Steve had become friends, Tony Stark even makes mention of how much admiration and respect his father had for Steve in the Avengers.  Howard Stark being one of the most gifted inventors on the planet also made an ideal choice to design advance machinery to assist in any recovery efforts of the Captain.